# Bullet points in Table - Reducing the space between rows

Tags: tables, spacing, excel2latex

I want to convert an Excel table which contains some bullets to a LaTeX table; for that purpose, I used the Excel2Latex plugin. When I pasted the (produced by the Plugin) code to Overleaf, I noticed that this bullet symbol · was changed a little bit (see 1st image ). I replaced this symbol to "\tabitem" and it worked out. My problem is that I do not like these large spaces between the bullets (see 2nd image). I think they are created since the item of the other table column has more than one line. How can I eradicate those?

I have attached the code.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\textbullet~~}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Vulnerability indicators to soil moisture and groundwater urban drought}
  \resizebox{0.95\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{21.945em}r}
    \toprule
    Soil Moisture & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{Groundwater} \\
    \midrule
    Exposure  & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{Exposure } \\
    \midrule
    Physical characteristics & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{Physical characteristics} \\
    \tabitem Potential evaporation based on the geographical location (indirect) & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Urban Groundwater Drought deficit based on past events} \\
    \tabitem Soil moisture drought deficit based on past events & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Average duration of Urban Groundwater Drought deficit based on past events} \\
    \tabitem Duration of Urban Soil moisture drought deficit based on past events & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Frequency of Standardized Groundwater Index (SGI)} \\
    \tabitem Frequency of Urban Soil Moisture Drought Events &  \\
    \midrule
    Sensitivity & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{Sensitivity} \\
    \midrule
    Physical characteristics & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{Physical characteristics} \\
    \tabitem Percentage of soils with high permeability & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Percentage of soils with high permeability} \\
    \tabitem Percentage of urban agricultural area to total city area & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Building density} \\
    \tabitem Percentage of urban gardens, parks, forests to total city’s area & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Percentage of building on wooden piles} \\
    \tabitem Percentage of parks which are irrigated & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Percentage of cultural heritage buildings on wooden piles} \\
    \tabitem Percentage of parks whose plants\textbackslash{}trees require little water & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Locations of critical infrastructure (e.g. hospital, electricity station)} \\
    \tabitem Existence of risk-reduced services & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Location of enterprises} \\
    Political characteristics  & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Groundwater extraction permits} \\
    \tabitem Existence of regulations regarding where parks, urban gardens, urban forests, and urban agricultural areas can be created and what kind of vegetation, crops, and tress can be planted & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{Social characteristics} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Population density} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Percentage of minority population whose house is on wooden piles} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Financial status of residents whose house is on wooden piles (this could be in adaptive capacity as well)} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{Political characteristics} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Existence of regulations regarding the way buildings ought to be erected  and type of materials ought to be used eradicating the use of wooden poles} \\
    \midrule
    Adaptive Capacity & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{Adaptive Capacity} \\
    \midrule
    Physical & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{Physical} \\
    \tabitem Water availability for irrigation & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Infiltration mechanisms to recharge the groundwater table if needed} \\
    \tabitem Water harvesting for watering urban parks & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{Socio-Economic} \\
    Socio-economic & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Educational level of residents (proxy for economic status) whose house is on wooden piles} \\
    \tabitem Unemployment rate (proxy for economic status) & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Gross domestic product if the analysis takes place for cities and not for neighborhoods} \\
    Political & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Public Budget Expenditure of the city} \\
    \tabitem Political status & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{Political} \\
    \tabitem Existence of Contingency plans & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Political status of the city} \\
    \tabitem Availability of water trucks for that water function & \multicolumn{1}{p{25.78em}}{\tabitem Existence of institutions with relevant competences} \\
    \tabitem Existence of institutions with relevant competences &  \\
    \end{tabular}%
    }
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Comment: Do not use `resizebox`on a table. This will lead to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: (i) conversion from Excel to LaTeX by ` Excel2Latex` generates a lot of redundant  (`\multicolumn{1}...`)., so in in generated code is easy to lost. So, please, cleanup your code.  (ii) empty vertical spaces are consequences of different number of lines in adjacent cells in rows. This can be removed, if you remove rows and replace `\tabitem` with `itemize` list. (ii) for further help please provide complete small document (MWE).

Comment: Please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your table is most likely too long to fit onto one page, I'd suggest using `longtable` in order to allow mid-table page breaks. I have also added a customized `tabitemize` environment for the use in tables.

As you can see from the following screenshow, not all vertical white spaces are removed since I decided to  vertically align the subheaders such as "Political characteristics" in order to increase the comparability of the list entries.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= * ,label=\textbullet,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

    \begin{longtable}{p{0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
    \caption{Vulnerability indicators to soil moisture and groundwater urban drought}
    \label{tab:addlabel}\\
    \toprule
    Soil Moisture & Groundwater \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption{Vulnerability indicators to soil moisture and groundwater urban drought - continued}\\
    \toprule
    Soil Moisture & Groundwater \\
    \midrule
    \endhead  
    Exposure  & Exposure  \\
    \midrule
    Physical characteristics 
    & Physical characteristics \\
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Potential evaporation based on the geographical location (indirect) 
    \item Soil moisture drought deficit based on past events
    \item Duration of Urban Soil moisture drought deficit based on past events
    \item Frequency of Urban Soil Moisture Drought Events
    \end{tabitemize}&
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Urban Groundwater Drought deficit based on past events 
    \item Average duration of Urban Groundwater Drought deficit based on past events 
    \item Frequency of Standardized Groundwater Index (SGI) 
    \end{tabitemize} \\
    \midrule
    Sensitivity & Sensitivity \\
    \midrule
    Physical characteristics & Physical characteristics \\*
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Percentage of soils with high permeability
    \item Percentage of urban agricultural area to total city area
    \item Percentage of urban gardens, parks, forests to total city’s area
    \item Percentage of parks which are irrigated
    \item Percentage of parks whose plants\textbackslash{}trees require little water
    \item Existence of risk-reduced services
    \end{tabitemize}& 
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Percentage of soils with high permeability
    \item Building density
    \item Percentage of building on wooden piles
    \item Percentage of cultural heritage buildings on wooden piles
    \item Locations of critical infrastructure (e.g. hospital, electricity station)
    \item Location of enterprises
    \item Groundwater extraction permits
    \end{tabitemize}\\ \addlinespace
      &  Social characteristics\\*
      &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Population density
    \item Percentage of minority population whose house is on wooden piles
    \item Financial status of residents whose house is on wooden piles (this could be in adaptive capacity as well)
    \end{tabitemize}\\ \addlinespace
    Political characteristics & Political characteristics \\*
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Existence of regulations regarding where parks, urban gardens, urban forests, and urban agricultural areas can be created and what kind of vegetation, crops, and tress can be planted
    \end{tabitemize}&
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Existence of regulations regarding the way buildings ought to be erected  and type of materials ought to be used eradicating the use of wooden poles
    \end{tabitemize}\\
    \midrule \pagebreak
    Adaptive Capacity & Adaptive Capacity \\
    \midrule
    Physical & Physical \\*
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Water availability for irrigation
    \item Water harvesting for watering urban parks
    \end{tabitemize}&
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Infiltration mechanisms to recharge the groundwater table if needed
    \end{tabitemize}\\ \addlinespace
    Socio-economic & Socio-economic \\*
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Unemployment rate (proxy for economic status)
    \end{tabitemize} &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Educational level of residents (proxy for economic status) whose house is on wooden piles
    \item Gross domestic product if the analysis takes place for cities and not for neighborhoods
    \end{tabitemize}\\ \addlinespace
    Political & Political \\*
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Political status
    \item Existence of Contingency plans
    \item Availability of water trucks for that water function
    \item Existence of institutions with relevant competences
    \end{tabitemize} &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Public Budget Expenditure of the city
    \item Political status of the city
    \item Existence of institutions with relevant competences
    \end{tabitemize}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}%


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me extend my comment to the answer. After cleanup code generated by `Excel2Latex` at conversion Excel table to LaTeX reorganizing of table was done. Instead of rows with `\tabitem` is introduced the `itemize` list.

On table design has strong inflece page layout. Since it is not know, I select for page borders sizes 25mm (by use of the `geometry` package), for table caption the `caption` package. With this table can be fit on one page.

For table environment is used `tabularx`, for list `enumitem` package:

[image]

(red lines indicate page page layout)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep=0pt,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 label=\textbullet,
                 after=\end{minipage},
                 before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                 }
\caption{Vulnerability indicators to soil moisture and groundwater urban drought}
\label{tab:addlabel}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XX@{}}
    \toprule
Soil Moisture & Groundwater     \\
    \midrule
% table body
Exposure  & Exposure            \\
    \midrule
\emph{Physical characteristics}
    &   \emph{Physical characteristics}     \\
    \begin{itemize}
\item Potential evaporation based on the geographical location (indirect)
\item Soil moisture drought deficit based on past events
\item Duration of Urban Soil moisture drought deficit based on past events
\item Frequency of Urban Soil Moisture Drought Events
    \end{itemize}
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Urban Groundwater Drought deficit based on past events
    \item Average duration of Urban Groundwater Drought deficit based on past events
    \item Frequency of Standardized Groundwater Index (SGI)
        \end{itemize}                       \\
    \midrule
Sensitivity & Sensitivity                   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Physical characteristics} 
    &   \emph{Physical characteristics}     \\
    \begin{itemize}
\item Percentage of soils with high permeability
\item Percentage of urban agricultural area to total city area
\item Percentage of urban gardens, parks, forests to total city’s area
\item Percentage of parks which are irrigated
\item Percentage of parks whose plants\textbackslash{}trees require little water
\item Existence of risk-reduced services\\

\hspace{-\leftmargin}\emph{Political characteristics}
    \item Existence of regulations regarding where parks, urban gardens, urban forests, and urban agricultural areas can be created and what kind of vegetation, crops, and tress can be planted
    \end{itemize}
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Percentage of soils with high permeability
    \item Building density
    \item Percentage of building on wooden piles
    \item Percentage of cultural heritage buildings on wooden piles
    \item Locations of critical infrastructure (e.g. hospital, electricity station)
    \item Location of enterprises
    \item Groundwater extraction permits\\

\hspace{-\leftmargin}\emph{Social characteristics}
    \item Population density
    \item Percentage of minority population whose house is on wooden piles
    \item Financial status of residents whose house is on wooden piles (this could be in adaptive capacity as well)
     \item Existence of regulations regarding the way buildings ought to be erected  and type of materials ought to be used eradicating the use of wooden poles
    \end{itemize}   \\
    \midrule 
Adaptive Capacity   & Adaptive Capacity \\
    \midrule
\emph{Physical}     &   \emph{Physical} \\
    \begin{itemize}
\item Water availability for irrigation
\item Water harvesting for watering urban parks\\

\hspace{-\leftmargin}\emph{Socio-economic}
\item Unemployment rate (proxy for economic status)\\    

\hspace{-\leftmargin}\emph{Political}
\item Political status
\item Existence of Contingency plans
\item Availability of water trucks for that water function
\item Existence of institutions with relevant competencies
    \end{itemize}
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Infiltration mechanisms to recharge the groundwater table if needed\\

\hspace{-\leftmargin}\emph{Socio-economic}
    \item Educational level of residents (proxy for economic status) whose house is on wooden piles
    \item Gross domestic product if the analysis takes place for cities and not for neighborhoods
     \item Public Budget Expenditure of the city\\

\hspace{-\leftmargin}\emph{Political}
    \item Political status of the city
    \item Existence of institutions with relevant competences
        \end{itemize}   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
If the text area borders are larger as are define in above MWE, you can use smaller font size for table, for example `\small` size and -- if needed -- also reduce baseline size, for example with `\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont`